# Callbacks in Objective C and Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase and after that update the table(`reloading data`).

```
-(void) findEvents{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    // Add a task to the group
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        [self fetchData];
    });

    // Add another task to the group
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        [self reloadTableData];
    });

    // Add a handler function for when the entire group completes
    // It's possible that this will happen immediately if the other methods have already finished
    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
        [self enjoyAfterwards];
    });
}
-(void)fetchData{
    [[ref child:@"calendar_event" ] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        for(FIRDataSnapshot* snap in snapshot.children){
            [self.allEvents addObject:[[GAEvent alloc] initWithParams: snap]];

        }
    }];
}
-(void)reloadTableData{
    NSLog(@"reloading table data");
}
-(void) enjoyAfterwards{
    NSLog(@"enjoying");
}
```

This is my [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186294/how-to-write-the-method-to-execute-after-completion-of-two-methods-ios). But I am getting the following output:

```
reloading table data
enjoying
// data is fetched
```

In Swift, I can use `callbacks` to achieve this. How do I do this in `Objective-C`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. you can use callbacks in ObjC

Comment: I am fetching data from firebase and after that reloading a table that is bound to those data. I have added both methods in the async queue but the reloading method is called prior to fetching data method and the table view data is not updated.

Comment: so you want `fetchData` -> `reloadTableData` -> `enjoyAfterwards`? just make `fetchData` takes a completion callback.

Comment: I can't find the syntax for completion handler in objective c .. can you plz add a link to do the same !

Comment: a quick search give me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436831/how-to-write-an-objective-c-completion-block

Comment: thanks! Let me try it..